# wsl is not working with localhost/rabbitmq

Tags: windows-10, python, localhost, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pip

So I have been working with a python library (t-bears) on a Ubuntu environment. For some reasons, I had to continue on my Window env.. I have installed Ubuntu from the Window store and got the the following error when I tried to work with t-bears :

```bsh
Connection refused: 500 - Connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 failed: timeout
Failed to connect to MQ. Check rabbitMQ service. (Connection closed)
```

I have read several post giving several explanations such as wsl not being able to properly interact with Window localhost, or problem with opening ports and even that it was on rabbitMQ side.

So I am a bit confused and I don't know what's the real cause of the problem. Thank you very much !

What I tried :
- Open port 5672
- Reinstall/reset rabbitMQ
- Removed NODE_IP_ADDRESS line from rabbitmq-env.conf

Comment: What is the Windows 10 version? What commands did you run or follow from an article?

Comment: Hi ! Got a Window 10 Family 1803 17134.885 , tried to open my firewall to the specific port, tried to reinstall/restart RabbitMQ, also tried to remove NODE_IP_ADDRESS from rabbitmq-env.conf